# Htaccess Manually inserted links not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I have edited my htaccess file for https redirection. But when we manually write https://domainname.com/fashion it is redirecting to [https://domainname.com/index.php?*route*=fashion](https://domainname.com/index.php?_route_=fashion).

My htaccess file looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [R=301, L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `R` flag from index rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L]
```

And move the https redirection to the top

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]
...
```